# Fetching an image from Reddit? JavaScript/React (no PRAW)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, reddit, imageurl

I'm trying to get images from Reddit based on my search parameters. I'm fetching fine and am able to retrieve my data, but the url I receive in `data.preview.images[0].source.url` (Reddit really buries it in there) are all prefixed with `https://external-preview.redd.it/`. When I click on the link in the response, I get a forbidden message.

I've seen videos where people are able to retrieve the images, but they are able to do so via a prefixed i-reddit link or what have you. I dug around for a bit in the JSON response but couldn't find any compatible links.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Here's my code with the fetching:

```
    state = {
        redditData: []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=animal_crossing`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(redditData => this.setState({redditData: redditData.data.children.slice(5, 10)}))
    }

    itsCardTime = () => {
        return this.state.redditData.map(rd => <RedditCard key={rd.id} data={rd.data}/>)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="homecontent">
                <div className="homeimage">
                    <h1 >cute image</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="redditdata">
                    {this.itsCardTime()}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And here's my code that should be rendering the image:

```
    render(){
        console.log(this.props.data)
    return(
        <div className="redditcard">
            <h5>
                {this.props.data.title}
                {/* {this.props.data.preview ? console.log(this.props.data.preview.images[0].resolutions[0].url) : null } */}
                {/* {this.props.data.preview ? <img src={this.props.data.preview.images[0].source.url}/> : null} */}
            </h5>
            <p>{this.props.data.subreddit_name_prefixed}</p>
        </div>
    )}
}
```

My responses are coming back in JSON format and I'm able to console log them.

Comment: Can you provide some code? how are you fetching the data, what data are you getting back?

Comment: yup! i edited the post with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, and am leaving the solution here as I expect others will run into this issue when fetching from Reddit after their upgrade. Basically, you have to escape the encoded URL that they are sending you. I did so with the following method:

```
getUrl = (imgUrl) => {
        let encoded = imgUrl.replace('amp;s', 's')
        let doubleEncoded = encoded.replace('amp;', '')
        let tripleEncoded = doubleEncoded.replace('amp;', '')
        return tripleEncoded
    }
```

though I'm sure there are other and better ways to get around it. I'll leave the link to my Reddit post in which a user directed me to this solution in case anyone wants to look into it and come up with something better for themselves.

https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/ihgw5j/cant_get_the_images_to_populate_from_my_fetch/